# Why does gprof think my function gets called when it doesn't?

Tags: c++, gprof

I have the following (completely useless) test code that I'm running through gprof.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int doFunc(int x)
{
    return x + 9;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The function doFunc is never used, but a  _GLOBAL__SUB_I_Z6doFunci  mangled name version shows up as being called once.  When I actually *call* the function, it just shows up as Z6doFunci, which gets called the appropriate amount of times, and the _GLOBAL_SUB version doesn't get called.

I noticed that, by removing iostream in the above code, the function never gets called (no _GLOBAL__SUB_ version).  So, I suspect that it has something to do with the initialization of the global objects contained in iostream, but other than that I'm stumped.  What is going on?